# gulp-file-include adds "artefacts" before every include

Tags: visual-studio-2015, gulp

I'm using "gulp-file-include" in a Visual Studio 2015 Project. The project purely uses static html files and the includes are also html files.

Everything works fine. But before every @@include I get this, which only shows up when I uses the inspect tools in the browser:

```
&#65279;
```

which will cause a line-break in my layout. When I look at the output-file in a text-editor "﻿" won't show up. The file is normally formatted.

[image]

I tried to normalize the formatting in my html file. But the problem still exists.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone posted a workaround, which resolves the described behaviour:

https://github.com/coderhaoxin/gulp-file-include/issues/93

The relevant part:

"I found a solution that sort of worked for me. I'm not suggesting it's the real solution though (RegEx and advanced string manipulation isn't my expertise). Below is the part of replace-operator.js I changed, with my additions commented with // Hack"

```
while (matchStart = regexpStart.exec(content)) {
startEnd = matchStart.index + matchStart[0].length;
matchBody = balanced('{', '}', content.slice(startEnd - 1))

if (matchBody && matchBody.start === 0) {
  matchEnd = regexpEnd ? regexpEnd.exec(matchBody.post) : true;

  if (matchEnd) {
    before = content.slice(0, matchStart.index);
    if(before.trim() == "") before = ""; // Hack: Added trim() here
    matchEnd = regexpEnd ? matchEnd[0].length : 0;
    replacement = opts.handler({
      before: before,
      args: matchStart[1],
      body: matchBody.body,
    });

    if (replacement !== undefined) {
      result += before + parse(replacement, opts);
      content = content.slice(startEnd + matchBody.end + matchEnd)
      continue;
    }
  }
}
result += content.slice(0, startEnd);
content = content.slice(startEnd);
}
result += content;
return result.trim(); // Hack: Added trim() here
```